# There are infinitely many $\frac{m}{n}\in\mathbb Q$ such that $|x- \frac{m}{n} |<\frac{1}{n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, irrational-numbers, real-numbers, diophantine-approximation

> Let $x$ be an irrational number. Prove that there are infinitely many rational numbers $\frac{m}{n}$ such that
>
> $$|x- \frac{m}{n} |<\frac{1}{n^2}$$

It's clear that $-1<1/n^2 <1$ with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. What I aim to prove is that given a irrational number $x$, I can find infinitely many rational numbers of the form $m/n$, such that the distance between $x$ and $m/n$ is less than the distance from $1/n^2$ and $0$.

With the Archimedian property of the Real numbers I found the following inequalities for some $m$:

$$\frac{1}{n^2}<\frac{m-1}{n}<x<\frac{m}{n}$$

But other than that I'm stucked in the problem.

Comment: Are the $n$'s the same for the rational and $1/n^2$?

Comment: see http://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/mbk-48-prev.pdf

Comment: In general it is not true. Consider $x=0$, $n=1$. Then there are no rationals of the form $\frac{m}{n}$ such that $|\frac{m}{n}|<1$

Comment: Your statement is false for rational $x$.

Comment: I made a mistake, $x$ should be irrational. And the n's are equal.

Comment: see p.196 in the middle, of the link I posted above, if you have not yet done so, it treats exactly the same question

Comment: This is Dirichlet's Theorem on Diiophantine Approximation, q.v. Historically, it was the first application of the Pigeonhole Principle.